# Date format issue dd/mm/yyyy C#

Tags: c#

Needing expert advice for date format issue . I have a string value `strDate= "03/04/2018"` which is `dd/mm/yyyy` . I am trying to convert into format dd mmm yyyy . If I use `(Convert.ToDateTime(strDate)).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")` , this results in `4 Mar 2018` instead of `3 Apr 2018` .

Can anyone please suggest if this is dependent on the system and regional setting ? Is it possible to make it work independent of regional settings ?

Comment: Call `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that it depends on your current culture.

Comment: You'll probably want to use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Comment: (Edited) `DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", null).ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for example. And if you want to be absolutely sure, use `DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.

Comment: @itsme86 Yeah, I did not get it right at first. Edited the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strDate = "03/04/2018";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            .ToString("d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Just posting code with no explanation makes for a _bad_ answer